# Display link with current user's username in it in Custom Menu

Tags: menus, users, buddypress

I'd like to add a link to BuddyPress' My Favourite Topics in a Custom Menu. Is there a way to use the current logged in user's username in the link?

I mean like the `%category%` in the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way how you can do it. To implement it properly I would recommend you to read [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) article. Especially pay attention on **Add Rewrite Tag** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the user's display name through get_currentuserinfo() function. You would first need to set the global then you can access the display name.

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Hello, ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Sorry, didn't noticed the date of the question before answering.

```
function add_favorites_link( $items, $args ) {
    // Check is user logged in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $ID = $user->ID;
        $fav = '<a href="'.bbp_get_favorites_permalink( $ID ).'">Favorites</a>';

        // Change the Menu Location to yours
        if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
            $items .= '<li>'.$fav.'</li>';
        }
        return $items;
    }   
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_favorites_link', 10, 2 );
```

That's a dirty workaround, but it will get you started.