# Current User In Custom Menu Item URL

Tags: menus, buddypress, s2member

I'm using S2Member + Buddypress on a compatible template. I have 8 menu items and am using the "Menu Items Visibility Control" to limit the 7th for view only to
`current_user_is(s2member_level1) | in_array('administrator', $GLOBALS['current_user']->roles)` This visibility is working correctly.

I'm in need of a way to create a custom menu item that will link to a page containing the following structure:

```
http://localhost/%%current_user_nicename%%/events/my-events/?action=edit
```

I don't know how to incorporate the current user name into the URL. I've come across this [post:](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53944/display-link-with-current-users-username-in-it-in-custom-menu).

*There must be an easy fix, if I leave a custom menu item's URL blank..can I specify the url elsewhere in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on figuring it out. 
Perhaps this would also work:

```
function change_menu($items){
  foreach($items as $item){

   if ($item-> post_name == 'the-slug')/*replace "the-slug" with menu item post_name */
        $item->url = bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '/events/my-events/?action=edit';

  }
  return $items;

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a filter function. This finds the nav menu obj matching the given slug and then modifies it's URL. I left the Menu item with visibility control in my dashboard menu. The URL is initially blank.

Added to functions.php:

```
function getUN()
{
    global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      return  $current_user->user_login;
}

function change_menu($items){
  foreach($items as $item){

if ($item-> post_name == 'the-slug')/*replace "the-slug" with menu item post_name */
{
    $item->url = get_site_url().'/members/'.getUN().'/events/my-events/?action=edit';

  }
  }
  return $items;

}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```